# Overloading >> operator is not setting attributes on input

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++, and trying to read in from cin to my object by overloading the >> operator. However, after the input, the object I create remains unchanged.

Header:

```
class Duration {
private:
    int hours, mins, secs;

public:
    Duration();
    Duration(int hours, int mins, int secs);
};

inline Duration::Duration() {
    this->hours = 0;
    this->mins = 0;
    this->secs = 0;
}

inline Duration::Duration(int hours, int mins, int secs) {
    this->hours = hours;
    this->mins = mins;
    this->secs = secs;
}

inline istream& operator>>(istream& is, Duration &d) {
    char c1, c2;

    int hours, mins, secs;

    if (is >> hours >> c1 >> mins >> c2 >> secs) {
        if (c1 == c2 == ':') {
            d = Duration(hours, mins, secs);
        }
        else {
            is.clear(ios_base::failbit);
        }
    }
    return is;
}

inline ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Duration &d) {
    return os << d.getHours() << ":"
              << d.getMins() << ":"
              << d.getSecs();
}
```

and my main:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Duration test;

    cin >> test;

    cout << test << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm pretty sure I've included all 'passing by reference' indications where needed, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Whatever I input when running the program, the resulting `Duration test` has the value `0:0:0`.

Comment: `if (c1 == c2 == ':')` has a precedence problem that the compiler may be warning you about.

Comment: Aha. This has fixed it! 0 warnings unfortunately. If you can make this the answer I'll accept gladly. Thankyou.

Comment: `c1 == c2 == ':'` will always be false `(c1 == c2) == ':'` -> `true == ':'`

Comment: Cranking up the warning level can be quite helpful. With gcc and similar compilers I use `-pedantic -Wall -Wextra` It's often worth adding on ` -Werror` so that the warnings can't be ignored. In Visual Studio go to Project->Properties->C/C++->general and set Warning level to Level4.

Comment: Related: *debugger*. Two breakpoints in a debugger and the problem is identified: one on the duration assignment `d = ...`, the other on the istream clear.

Comment: @RichardCritten: *" will always be false"* We might have/create a layout with `':'` as 1 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`if (c1 == c2 == ':')` was the issue as pointed out, evaluating to `true == ':'` which of course equals `false`. I fixed it with `if (c1 == c2 && c2 == ':')` (not sure if most efficient, but certainly now works as intended).

Comment: Sure. Thanks again